# Select entire columns

Tags: excel, select, multiple-columns, vba

I have a range activated `Range(strPlageSélectionnée).Activate`, and i'm looking for selecting their entire columns in order to delete them. 
I know that to select a column there is a specific formula `ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select`
and to delete one column it's `ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete`

But how can i select and delete many columns at once. Is there any specific formula ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't select columns to delete them, in fact you should rarely be selecting anything programmatically.

I suspect your columns are not next to each other so this will work.

```
Range("C:C,F:F,I:I").Delete
```

Notice .select and selection were chopped off and the code combined to one line instead of:

```
Range("C:C,F:F,I:I").select
Selection.Delete
```

Comment: What if you have a range like A4:G10? How do extract just the columns? In the first sentence, OP says he needs to select the columns of his range to delete them.

Comment: See @crimmyjif answer below. Yes the OP said they need to select the columns to delete them but no they don't, Looking at the OP's code samples it looks like output from the macro recorder which will select then delete, this doesn't need to be done and is inefficient.

Comment: For non contiguous you can use this: `Range("A1,C1,E1").entirecolumn.Delete`

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace ActiveCell with the Range.

```
Range("C4:F10").EntireColumn.Delete
```